# MySQL LIKE not working

Tags: mysql, wpdb

It seems MySQL's LIKE operator behaves like a = operator.

The following MySQL query returns the expected result (1 entry):

```
$meta_key = '_locality';
$meta_value = 'The Hague';
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
  "
  SELECT      post_id
  FROM        $wpdb->postmeta
  WHERE       meta_key = %s
              AND meta_value LIKE %s
  ", 
  $meta_key, 
  $meta_value
) );
```

But the following returns an empty array:

```
$meta_key = '_locality';
$meta_value = 'The';
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
  "
  SELECT      post_id
  FROM        $wpdb->postmeta
  WHERE       meta_key = %s
              AND meta_value LIKE %s
  ", 
  $meta_key, 
  $meta_value
) );
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't automatically do a substring match. Try "The%" rather than just "The" where `%` is a wildcard.

Comment: The title of this question is perhaps best read in Valleyspeak. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
AND meta_value LIKE %s
```

with

```
AND meta_value LIKE '%%%s%%'
```

so your SQL will become:

```
AND meta_value LIKE '%The%'
```

instead of:

```
AND meta_value LIKE 'The'
```

Comment: This is certainly correct, one thing I think should be noted is: [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [`WP_Meta_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) are by default constructing the SQL like this, if `LIKE` is given for `compare`. So generally raw SQL isn't needed to achieve this.

Comment: @ialocin yes I agree and it's a good point you make, usually there's no reason for constructing SQL by hand since the `WP*Query` classes are rather flexible. But it helps understanding the WordPress core (at least a tiny part of it)  of course to know how to construct the SQL queries ;-)

Comment: true, just added it for others to know

Comment: the reason I needed this SQL query is that I need to make a query with multiple relations - one OR and then AND - which I believe is not possible with WP_Query

Comment: this is exactly why my wordpress wildcard LIKE % was not working, now working thanks to this answer!

Comment: glad to hear it helped @luke_mclachlan